# Getting infinity loop while checking factors of a number in while loop

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with `infinite loop` problem while Array exercise implementation which needs to be done with Java Script functional way:
I have a code which creates an array and fills its values with numbers which fulfil condition:

```
Each array element has a value,
which we draw from the range <100, 200> until the sum of digits is
a number having exactly two dividers, not counting 1 and this one
numbers.
```

I have a code like below:

```
const generateNumber = (min, max) =>
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + Math.floor(min);

const unities = number => number % 10;
const hundreds = number => Math.floor((number % 1000) / 100);
const tens = number => Math.floor((number % 100) / 10);

const sumDigits = (number) => unities(number) + hundreds(number) + tens(number);

const countNumberFactors = number => Array
.from(Array(number + 1), (_, i) => i)
.filter(i => number % i === 0)
.slice(1, -1)
    .length;

const generateNumberUntilConditionNotAchieve = (min, max) => {
  let number = generateNumber(min, max);
  const digitsSum = sumDigits(number);
  while (countNumberFactors(digitsSum) === 2) {
    number = generateNumber(min, max)
  }
  return number;
}

const generateArray = (minArrSize, maxArrSize, minItemValue, maxItemValue) =>
    Array(generateNumber(minArrSize, maxArrSize))
    .fill(0)
    .map(
        () => generateNumberUntilConditionNotAchieve(minItemValue,
            maxItemValue));

const main = () => {
  const generatedArray = generateArray(1, 5, 100, 200);
  console.log("Array -> " + generatedArray);
}

main();
```

For small `minArraySize` and `maxArraySize` values sometimes I am receiving desirable result but for params like <10, 100> my IDE is freezing. On online editor with pasted above code, I am receiving information about the infinite loop on line:

```
while (countNumberFactors(digitsSum) === 2)
```

I tried to investigate a root cause by trial and error but I did not find out a solution. I will be grateful for suggestions on how to solve the above `infinite loop` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing `number` but checking `digitsSum`. All you need to do to fix this is add `digitsSum = sumDigits(number)` in the while loop. e.g.

```
const generateNumberUntilConditionNotAchieve = (min, max) => {
  let number = generateNumber(min, max);
  const digitsSum = sumDigits(number);
  while (countNumberFactors(digitsSum) === 2) {
    number = generateNumber(min, max);
    digitsSum = sumDigits(number);
  }
  return number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million, tiredness took over.. Now it's working as expected.

Comment: @Martin Don't worry, we've all made a mistake like this. Make sure to mark as answer so future googles see the solution!

Comment: I will, need 3 minutes more. Thanks!